# Is there a XAML equivalent to CSS's grid-area?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Does WPF XAML have an equivalent to CSS's [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area)? I.e., a way to create a definition of `Row`, `Column`, `RowSpan`, `ColumnSpan` values, give that definition an identifier, and then use those values via the identifier?

I am imagining something like:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.AreaDefinitions>
    <AreaDefinition Row="0" Column="0" ColumnSpan="2" Name="Header" />
    <AreaDefinition Row="1" Column="0" Name="Navigation" />
    <AreaDefinition Row="1" Column="1" Name="Main" />
    <AreaDefinition Row="2" Column="0" ColumnSpan="2" Name="Footer" />
  </Grid.AreaDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Area="Header" Text="Header" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Area="Navigation" Text="Navigation" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Area="Main" Text="Main" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Area="Footer" Text="Footer" />
</grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't support this directly, but it's easy enough to implement with dependency properties and attached properties. First you'll need a class for your AreaDefinition:

```
public class AreaDefinition : DependencyObject
{
    public int Row
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Row", typeof(int), typeof(AreaDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int Column
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Column", typeof(int), typeof(AreaDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int RowSpan
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(RowSpanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RowSpanProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RowSpanProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RowSpan", typeof(int), typeof(AreaDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(1));

    public int ColumnSpan
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnSpanProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnSpanProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnSpanProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnSpan", typeof(int), typeof(AreaDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(1));

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(AreaDefinition), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
}
```

You'll also need a class to hold a collection of these, in much the same way that Grid.Columns is a collection of type ColumnDefinitionCollection:

```
public class AreaDefinitionCollection : Collection<AreaDefinition>
{
}
```

Last, you'll need a class for your attached properties, which I'll call GridHelper. This class will need to provide two APs, one for your Grids (`GridHelper.AreaDefinitions`) and another for the Grid's children (`GridHelper.Area`). The change handler for `GridHelper.AreaProperty` is where all the magic happens, it simply updates the associated `Grid` APs whenever the Area changes:

```
public static class GridHelper
{
    public static AreaDefinitionCollection GetAreaDefinitions(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (AreaDefinitionCollection)obj.GetValue(AreaDefinitionsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAreaDefinitions(DependencyObject obj, AreaDefinitionCollection value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AreaDefinitionsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AreaDefinitionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AreaDefinitions", typeof(AreaDefinitionCollection), typeof(Grid), new PropertyMetadata(new AreaDefinitionCollection()));

    public static string GetArea(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(AreaProperty);
    }

    public static void SetArea(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AreaProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AreaProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Area", typeof(string), typeof(UIElement), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnAreaChanged));

    private static void OnAreaChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement child = d as UIElement;
        if (child == null)
            return;
        Grid grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child) as Grid;
        if (grid == null)
            return;
        AreaDefinitionCollection areas = GetAreaDefinitions(grid);
        if (areas == null)
            return;

        // the performance of this bit could be improved by giving AreaDefinitionCollection a hash table implementation, oh well.               
        var areaDefinition = areas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == e.NewValue.ToString());
        if (areaDefinition == null)
            return;

        // update the grid elements
        Grid.SetRow(child, areaDefinition.Row);
        Grid.SetRowSpan(child, areaDefinition.RowSpan);
        Grid.SetColumn(child, areaDefinition.Column);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(child, areaDefinition.ColumnSpan);
    }
}
```

With this in place you can implement the functionality you're after, with some minor modifications:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <g:GridHelper.AreaDefinitions>
        <g:AreaDefinition Row="0" Column="0" ColumnSpan="2" Name="Header" />
        <g:AreaDefinition Row="1" Column="0" Name="Navigation" />
        <g:AreaDefinition Row="1" Column="1" Name="Main" />
        <g:AreaDefinition Row="2" Column="0" ColumnSpan="2" Name="Footer" />
    </g:GridHelper.AreaDefinitions>

    <TextBlock g:GridHelper.Area="Header" Text="Header" />
    <TextBlock g:GridHelper.Area="Navigation" Text="Navigation" />
    <TextBlock g:GridHelper.Area="Main" Text="Main" />
    <TextBlock g:GridHelper.Area="Footer" Text="Footer" />
</Grid>
```

If you don't like the `g:` namespace prefix then you can get rid of it, as specified in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and), by adding the following line to your AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "YourGridHelperNamespace")]
```

Comment: i continue to be amazed by the power of WPF

Comment: It's very powerful. Sometimes a little _too_ much so. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything exactly like that, but there is a feature that could be used similarly. [Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview#styles) are "a convenient way to apply a set of property values to multiple elements". Whever you have a number of elements which all need to have the same properties set to the same value, you can define a `Style`, like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="AStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource AStyle}" Text="Header" />
</Grid>
```

In your example code, this would be useless, because none of the `TextBlock`s share a complete set of values- you don't save any redundant code because it's only used once anyway. But a `grid-area`, if it existed, would be equally useless for the same reason.

Comment: upon re-visiting this topic, i realized this answer is correct in a "oh, that's so obvious" sort of way. the problem i was trying to solve is: you have a grid with 20 rows. now you want to insert a new row near the top. now you have to modify the row number on everything after the thing you inserted.